# no update excels chart while holding slider

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I put some chart and slider in my excel sheet. As I draging slider then data in my sheet is chaning however my chart update only when I release my slider. I need to update my chart live even as I use slider. Any solutions?

Comment: "chart update only when I release my slider" - that's probably by design in Excel and you can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a scrollbar from the ActiveX menu of controls, the chart should update while you slide it. The Form control slider doesn't work the way you want.

Of course, ActiveX controls can be a bit flaky, and they will not work at all on a Mac.